# Angular js http get as a service for all the routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

In each and every routes (15 routes) I want to show the user information. So i'm calling the user profile API ($http get) as service in all the routes like this

```
function getProfile() {
      userServices.getProfile().then(function (response) {
        vm.profile = response.data;
       });
};
```

Instead of calling same API on every routes, Can I fetch the user information once and use it on all the places wherever I need?

I'm aware of services in angular, and I referred this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30780328/1409399 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40203432/1409399. Can I go with this solution? Will it work for this case? Sorry I did not try this solutions yet. Please advice

Comment: I believe that it will work. Another question, are those different views nested states?

Comment: All are different views and it's not nested states.

Comment: Ok, because solve the request in to resolve clause maybe another option. But I think your solution is OK. Another one (will depends on the amount of data that you wanna store) could store that user info in your sessionStorage.

Comment: Yes you can go with thi solution, each service is created once per app - this doesnt depend on states anyhow.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let me try it out.